# How to add external libraries in NetBeans IDE?

Tags: java, jar

I downloaded the jar 4.3.1-bin.zip in http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi
But I don't know how to use it, I added JAR in Lib folder in Netbeans but it not resolved my problem

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

these imports yet "org.apache.http.xxxxx" does not exist

Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick solution in NetBeans 6.8.

In the Projects window right-click on the name of the project that lacks library -> Properties -> The Project Properties window opens. In Categories tree select "Libraries" node -> On the right side of the Project Properties window press button "Add JAR/Folder" -> Select jars you need.

Comment: well, i have did it another way, but this way help me... thanks