# Imports from org.apache

Tags: java, apache, ntp

I am unable to find the JAR files I need to download for these:

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ntp.NTPUDPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ntp.TimeInfo;
```

Sorry it may sound stupid to you, but I really could not find what to download at the time this question was asked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add external libraries in NetBeans IDE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303453/how-to-add-external-libraries-in-netbeans-ide)

Comment: I don't know. Read the answer in that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/download_net.cgi and Download the jars and then import them in library in your java program.